# Azure AutoML download metrics

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I was wondering if there is a way to download the metrics for a model after a run has completed in AutoML in Azure?  For example, I want to download the generated confusion matrix as a png file along with the other available metrics.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`AutoMLRun`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-train-automl-client/azureml.train.automl.run.automlrun?view=azure-ml-py)'s `get_output()` method to do so -- check out [this notebook example](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/automated-machine-learning/regression/auto-ml-regression.ipynb).

If you're  using the UI to create `AutoML` runs, or need an output from a  previously submitted run, you'll  have to create  a new `AutoMLRun()` instance  using an Experiment object and the `run_id`, like below.

```py
import azureml.core
from azureml.core.experiment import Experiment
from azureml.core.workspace import Workspace
froom azureml.train.automl.run import AutoMLRun

ws = Workspace.from_config()
experiment_name = 'YOUREXPERIMENTNAME'
experiment = Experiment(ws, experiment_name)

run_automl = AutoMLRun(experiment, run_id="YOUR RUN ID")

best_run, fitted_model = remote_run.get_output()
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot download the confusion matrix or other visualizations from AutoML. You can get a link to the UI from the run and view visualizations there. Why do you need this from the Python SDK?

Also, you can see visualizations through the RunDetails widget.